# What is the procedure to replace carpets in airliners?

Tags: aircraft-maintenance

Are all the seats removed, as well as trim and baseboard, before the carpet is replaced? If so, how is reinstalling the seats laid out; do they feel for the boltholes? Are the seats bolted on top of the carpet or directly to the floor?

Comment: Hobbes' answer seems to assume that you are asking about airliners. However, I don't think that's a given. Can you [Edit] to specify the kind of aircraft you're asking about?

Comment: I was asking about airliners, and Hobbes' answer was exactly what I was after. Thanks, Hobbes'.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, Frank. I edited your question's title to clarify this. If you feel I got your intent wrong, by all means feel free to edit further.

Comment: If you feel that Hobbes' answer answers your question, you should indicate so by accepting it, by clicking the checkmark outline next to the voting buttons for the answer.

Answer (score 4):

The seats are installed on rails, so they can be easily removed (or moved to a different seat pitch). The bolts are [in plain sight](https://apex.aero/2017/04/04/recaro-slides-aix-2017-airbus-a320-cabin-reconfiguration-flex-seat) (random source for example photo).

[image]

The carpets are laid around the rails. I suspect the carpet does not protrude underneath the base board, so they'd only have to remove the seats to get the carpet out.

This is the inside of an [airliner with the seats and carpet removed](http://aeroengltd.com/aircraft-cabin-refurbishments.html):

[image]